# Rails 3.1 + Devise: The default routes for Devise aren't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I'm getting the following error when I try to access the "sign in" route (GET /users/sign_in)...

```
No route matches {:action=>"home", :controller=>"devise/pages"}
```

Here's the full error from the server log...

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-05 00:51:54 -0700
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (2.9ms)
Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (33.5ms)
Rendered pages/_header.html.erb (75.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 349ms

ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"home", :controller=>"devise/pages"}):
```

Here's the body of my application/layout...

```
<!-- BEGIN body -->
<body class="top">

    <!-- BEGIN .container -->
    <div class="container">

        <%= render 'pages/header' %>
        <%= render 'pages/menu' %>

        <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
        <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>

        <%= yield %>

    <!-- END .container -->
    </div>

    <%= render 'pages/footer' %>

</body>
```

The only controller I have is the "pages" controller.  Also, here's my route.rb file...

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
  match '/news', :to => 'pages#news'
  match '/home', :to => 'pages#home'
  match '/features', :to => 'pages#features'

  root :to => 'pages#home'

end
```

I don't know if it has anything to do with it, but I also generated the views using the `rails generate devise:views` command.

Why is it trying to access the nonexistent "devise/pages" controller and the "home" action when I do a GET /users/sign_in?  That's not what my routes show when I do `rake routes`...

```
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        {:action=>"cancel", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                    root        /                              {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"home"}
                 contact        /contact(.:format)             {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"contact"}
                    news        /news(.:format)                {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"news"}
                    home        /home(.:format)                {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"home"}
                features        /features(.:format)            {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"features"}
```

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

*EDIT* Adding the "pages/menu" partial by request...

```
<!-- BEGIN .menu-primary -->
    <div class="menu-primary">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/news">News</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/features"><span>Shop Products</span></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="/features">Features</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span>Shop Parts</span></a><ul><li><a href="#">Controls (Coming Soon)</a></li><li><a href="#">Monitors (Coming Soon)</a></li><li><a href="#">Artwork (Coming Soon)</a></li><li><a href="#">Accessories (Coming Soon)</a></li></ul></li>
                        <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <!-- END .menu-primary -->
    </div>
```

*UPDATE* In my header template, I had...

```
<%= link_to image_tag("mylogo.png", :alt=>"", :width=>"300", :height=>"100"), {:action => 'home', :controller => 'pages'} %>
```

and removing this allows my sign_in page to load successfully.  Why?!

Comment: root path should usually be at the bottom of your routes

Comment: thanks for the tip! tho it didn't change anything.

Comment: Did you restart your server? Can you give me the full error message?

Comment: Yes, I tried restarting the server.  Also, I just added the full error message.  That shows that it looks like it's trying to render my 'home' view for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: hi beachrunnerjoe. what is the full url in your browser's address bar when the error occurs? Are you typing the url directly, or following `new_user_session_path`? Do you have a User model with all the required divisable fields? If so, you may want to add a prefix to your routes to avoid conflicts between Devise and your user model `devise_for :users,  :path_prefix => 'session'`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does your 'pages/menu' partial look like? It looks like that's where the error might be occurring, based on the stack trace. I wonder if there's a link to something like 'pages/home' within the partial that, for some reason, assumes it should be looking for the partial under the devise namespace.

Comment: @Andy Harvey, the full URL in my browser that I'm trying directly is http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/sign_in. Thanks!

Comment: @Adam, I just updated my question with the menu partial. Your thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: thanks @BeachRunnerJoe, did you try adding a `:path_prefix`? Bear in mind that the normal URL format is model/id. So with your path, Rails is looking for a user with `ID == sign_in`. You need to differentiate these two paths.

Comment: BTW, my previous comment assumes you have `resource :user` set up in your routes. If you don't, you can ignore me. :)

Comment: Thanks for posting @BeachRunnerJoe, nothing jumps out at me in the menu partial. I would guess somewhere in one of the templates that's being rendered in that call there is a dynamic link to pages#home that's being set up but, for whatever reason, it's being treated as if it's under the devise namespace. Not sure though, could be something else.

Comment: @Adam, you were right, I had "<%= link_to image_tag("mylogo.png", :alt=>"", :width=>"300", :height=>"100"), {:action => 'home', :controller => 'pages'} %>" in my "header" template and removing it allowed the sign_in page to load.  What gives?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When constructing the URL for `{:action => 'home', :controller => 'pages'}`, Rails uses paths relative to the controller rendering the current view.
For the sign-in page, that would be "devise/sessions", hence it looks for the PagesController in the `devise` namespace.

You can fix it by adding a backslash to specify that the controller is in the root, not within the devise namespace.

Replace:

```
{:action => 'home', :controller => 'pages'}
```

with this:

```
{:action => 'home', :controller => '/pages'}
```

Answer (score 1):

> "", :width=>"300", :height=>"100"), root_path %>

I believe the link_to url that was passed is scoped to devise.  You should the path name that was generated from rake routes instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem installing Devise and after that, couldn't run anything. But in my case i tried to solve it using the routes which Rails pointing on the routes page:

```html
<%= link_to 'Home', {:controller => 'frontpages', :action => 'services'}, class: 'footer-nav-link' %>
  
To:
  
<%= link_to 'Services', frontpages_services_path, class: 'footer-nav-link' %>
```

And everything run after.

Answer (score -1):

I found place where to add backslash '/' in start of controller in relative file where error will be shown in relative file(see error at i.e. development.log)
In my case:

```
= link_to "About", :controller => "/pages", :action => "about"
```

or

```
= link_to "Home", :controller => "/pages", :action => "home"
```